# Is there a ruby/rails gem that makes scoping dates easy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, rubygems

anyone know of a gem that makes scoping dates easy? I'd love to do Model.this_year(:created_at).where()... etc. Thought I heard of one once.

I was thinking something along the lines of dues_paid_this_year or updated_at_two_hours_ago. A gem that could do this like search_logic by creating dynamic scopes would make my world lovely

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a gem–although it would be very cool to create one. That being said, this would probably get you by:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Some date-related scopes
  scope :today, where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
  scope :yesterday, where("created_at < ? and created_at > ?", 1.day.ago.end_of_day, 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day)
  scope :this_month, where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month)
  scope :last_month, where("created_at < ? and created_at > ?", 1.month.ago.end_of_month, 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month)
  scope :this_year, where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_year)
  ### 
  # All your model stuff goes here
  ###

  # Let's get real tricky with method_missing 
  # and allow Thing.last_X_days for work for any value of X
  private

  def self.method_missing(method, *args, &block) 
    if method.to_s =~  /^last_(\d+)_days$/i
      days = method.to_s.match(/^last_(\d+)_days$/i)
      return self.where("created_at > ?", days[1].to_i.days.ago.beginning_of_day)
    else
      super
    end
  end   

end
```

This will give you some basic scopes like Thing.this_month ... plus a dynamic finder that will let you do something like Thing.last_90_days and work for any number (WARNING: I'm a bit of a method_missing n00b, the code worked for me but maybe someone can double-check it).

FYI I'm assuming Rails 3 here.

Comment: I got bit by this before - in your scopes for `Thing.today` and `Thing.this_month`, etc - those `Time`s are generated at server spinup. That means `Thing.today` will give the all the `Thing`s that were created on or after the day the server was _started_, not the current time. (Unless I'm misreading code or some voodoo is happening)

Comment: Also, whenever implementing a `method_missing`, I believe it's good practice to implement the corrresponding `respond_to?`: http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/30

Comment: @Jamie when you say "server", do you mean the current apache/nginx server instance–or the actual box? I've never run into this and Time.now in a console always seems accurate for me.

Comment: Sorry, I might have not been clear. The problem isn't with ruby, the problem is _when_ this is evaluated. The `Time.now.beginning_of_day` gets evaluated when the class is declared (which happens on the rails server spinup). So whenever you try to use that scope, it's comparing it against that value, which is evaluated only once. Read the box in yellow about why `lambda` is needed here: `http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html`

Comment: @Callmeed, could you please correct your code above to use the lambda, I'd hate send people in the wrong direction...

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do what you want with lambda scopes?